# Unable to get the desired result if password contains dollar ($) character while running openssl passwd -apr1 command

Tags: java, shell, openssl

I am running the following command to generate the hash for a given password on the Linux terminal.

```
openssl passwd -apr1 'Test123$Pwd' 
$apr1$lWLP.Qc0$f/YdAVqsYFglu1EnLvzUS.
```

I have written a simple shell script that generates a hash for the given password. Here is my shell script:  (Should I modify anything here in shell script to include single quotes surrounding $1)

echo -n "$1" | openssl passwd -apr1 $1

Now, the problem is, when I call the same shell script from java program, for some reason if the password contains a dollar($) character, it is not working as expected.

Here is my java code which calls the above shell script:

```
void test(String password){
    String script = "sh test.sh %s";
    String command = String.format(script, password);
    - - - 
    execute(command); // execute using ProcessBuilder
    - - - 
 }
```

The above code works fine if the password doesn't contain a dollar character. But, if the password contains $ char, it ignores the text after the $ symbol and generates a hash for the remaining password only up to $.

For example: If I pass the password as **Test$Pwd**

The hash is getting generated for only **Test** instead of **Test$Pwd**

I tried to set a single quote in java code as below but this also didn't work. When executed using java for some reason it still generates the hash for **Test123** instead of **Test123$Pwd**

Modified java code to include a single quote as below:

```
"sh test.sh '%s'";
```

Observed the followed command in logs which has single quotes, and this also didn't work when I ran shell script from java.

```
openssl passwd -apr1 'Test123$Pwd'
```

From the Linux terminal when I run the script it works fine.

```
sh test.sh 'Test123$Pwd'  -- this works
sh test.sh Test123$Pwd    -- this doesn't work (generates hash only for Test123 even when run directly on the linux terminal)
```

I am confused about whether I need to modify the shell script or something in java?

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: For ProcessBuilder, the command is a *list* of strings: `new ProcessBuilder("sh", "test.sh", password);`

Comment: And inside the shell script, use double quotes around `"$1"` *everywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

In shell scripts, double quotes is a way to get around spaces being seen as delimiters. It doesn't exclude variable substitution. So that's what you want here; single quotes would pass the literal `$1` as in, the dollar, then the 1, and not 'substitute the first argument of the script here'. However, you pass $1 straight up without quotes for the second.

But, this is putting rather a lot of dependency on the exact shell in use and opens up doors to passwords with certain symbols messing up your program.

Why not forego the shell script entirely and call `openssl` directly? You can replace the standard in (and thus, send what echo is sending in your script), and the args passed via `ProcessBuilder`'s `List<String>` / `String...` options (never use the single string option, really, it's hard to read and is asking java to attempt to turn spaces into separators, bad idea here) - as now you're passing the raw options without bash or whatever shell you have attempting to 'interpret' that password which you don't want it to do.

Or, better yet, why are you invoking a shell script?

apr1 is, if memory serves, the crypt key indicating 'MD5, done 1000 times'. This is a **HORRIBLE**, in that it is trivially rainbow tabled and broken, way of hashing passwords. It's also something you don't need openssl for at all, you can easily do that from java.

So, here's my advice:

1. Reconsider apr1. It's insecure as heck, you don't want it. Use bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf2. Probably bcrypt.
2. Stop farming this job out via an exec, do it in java. For example, use [jBCrypt](https://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).